# How can termux accept key presses directly into terminal?

Tags: keyboard

I just installed termux and I notice that when you use the keyboard it doesn't enter your key presses directly. It requires you to complete a word and select from the options before it gets entered into the terminal.

Is there a way to enter the key presses into the terminal right away?

Comment: Termux does not behave that way on any of my devices so I cannot duplicate the problem. If reinstalling does not fix it then perhaps you could edit your question with more information about your device, android version and how you have it set up.